# Populating the configuration to the nested library project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, configuration, static-libraries

I have a main project, which includes a nested library project which produces a `libCore.a` library.

Both of the projects have the two configurations `debug` and `release`. Now if I build the main project with a given configuration, how can I make sure that this is passed down to the library project as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your project directly dependent on the `libCore` project. Do achieve this, do the following:

1. Drag the `libCore` project file to your main project. It happens sometimes, that only the *xcodeproj* file is moved. If this happens to you, restart XCode (this happend to me with RestKit and the latest XCode).
2. After point 1 is done and you can browse the dependency project, go to your target build phases and add the `libCore` as the target dependencies.
3. Link against `libCore.a` by adding in the **Link Binary with Libraries** phase.

These are 3 basic steps, I don't know what the `libCore` is, if it needs to be linked with any other libraries then you will also have to link your target against those libraries.